# How to integrate f(x) * f"(x)

Tags: integration

Suppose $f, f"$ is cts everywhere. Evaluate $\int f(x)f"(x)dx$

I thought I should start with IBP,

$u = f(x) du$

$= f'(x)dx dv= f"(x)dx v= f'(x)$

$=f(x)f'(x) - \int f'(x)f'(x)dx$

I went for second IBP:

$u = f'(x) du = f"(x)dx dv= f'(x)dx v= f(x)$

$=f(x)f'(x) - (f(x)f'(x) - \int f(x)f"(x)dx)$

now I am stuck i have no clue how to proceed. I thought i could use this to bring the second integral to the right and div the integrals by 2. But if I were to do that then it would equal 0.

$=f(x)f'(x) - f(x)f'(x) + \int f(x)f"(x)dx$

What should I do?

Comment: its second dervative

Comment: For Mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @AlphaDJog: Ahh OK, sorry for my reading problems. :-)